# c# local database / dataset

Tags: c#, database, dataset, local

I'm new on C# and I want to have my data on a local database. The problem is I can't understand how to do it. I created a sgt.sdf (database) file and a sgtDataSet.xsd (dataset) but I don't seem to understand the relation between those two files. Can anyone explain me how to work properly with this?

Comment: I don't have the heart to downvote this, but you really need to _show_ some more research.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to C# and learning it, so you should be able to start learning about databases, example databases on a SQL Server or likewise.

Or you could use a localDB if you don't want to setup a SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna start with something less cnfusing, i sugest using an access database. Sdf databases are u reliable. They can be broken without even knowing.
When using access you will be using the OleDB code in C# it's almost the same as the other ones.

Hope it helped :)